# How to redirect to previous page in admin?

Tags: url, get, magento-1.7, admin

In my admin controller action I want to redirect to redirect to the previous page? How can I do this? 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

I'm using Magento CE 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code did worked.

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

Hope this would help someone.

Comment: Works great. I even threw a success message in before the redirect:
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess('Sent label to printer.');